# Вы никто и звать вас никак - это оскорбление?

Tags: этимология

Интересует следующий вопрос, обращение к человеку "Вы никто и звать Вас никак" является ли оскорблением? Возможно сможете подсказать, в каких литературных произведениях это выражение используется. Хочу отметить, что данное выражение использовалось в отношении человека, который не обладал полномочиями, которые пытался исполнить.

Answer (score 4):

Никто, и звать тебя никак - это фразеологизм, причём с явным презрительным оттенком.А. И. Фёдоров во "Фразеологическом словаре русского литературного языка" 2008 г.и. Даёт ему следующее  значение: *"Совершенно чужой, посторонний человек, с кем нет и быть не может ничего общего"*. Говоря подобные вещи вы фактически заявляете, что подобный человек попросту недостоин общаться с вами, так он чуть ли не скотина бессловесная. Оскорбляться или нет это уже дело слушателя, но оскорбить подобной фразой вполне возможно, особенно если не обозначить, что "никто и никак, человек, только в том вопросе в который он без необходимости влез.

> *Слышь, Катя, а Ваське-то, говорят, ногу сломали вчера… В драке. Теперь и по больничному платить не будут… Что молчишь-то? — А что мне, — взъярилась Катерина, — слёзы лить, что ли? Кто он мне? Никто, ничто и звать никак!*
> (Ю. Брагуль. Новый день)
>
> *Мама, ну, что ты, — сказала Алёна… Да он мне никто и звать никак. Ну, честно…*
> (А. Чупров. Тройная медь)

Answer (score 2):

Для начала разберемся со значением слово "оскорбить". ОСКОРБИТЬ, -1)
Крайне обидеть, унизить кого-л.; уязвить в ком-л. какие-л. чувства. О. чью-л. честь, гордость. Смертельно о. чьё-л. достоинство. Оскорбить кого-л. действием
(нанести кому-л. удары, побои). //
2)Осквернить, унизить чем-л. неподобающим. О. торжественность минуты глупой выходкой. О. в лучших чувствах. О. чей-л. слух, зрение, взор
(быть крайне неприятным для чьего-л. слуха, зрения). < Оскорблять, -яю, -яешь; нсв. Оскорбляться, -яется; страд. (см.).

Оскорбле́ние — умышленное унижение чести и достоинства личности, часто выраженное в неприличной форме.

Оскорбление может быть нанесено в виде высказывания (словесно, письменно) или в виде действия (плевок, неприличный жест), а также публично или в отсутствие объекта оскорбления. Во многих странах оскорбление считается преступлением.

В отличие от клеветы, оскорбление не несёт в себе сведений, позорящих потерпевшего. Оскорбление заключается в негативной оценке личности человека, его качествам, поведению, причём в форме, противоречащей установленным правилам поведения и требованиям общечеловеческой морали(Википедия). Звучит, конечно, грубо. Но все зависит от контекста. В данном случае, несмотря на оттенок грубости,  вряд ли можно считать оскорблением. Говорящий имел в виду, что человек к которому обращена речь, не имеет никаких прав и полномочий. Слово никто имеет несколько значений. 1. НИКТО, никого; м. и ж. Разг.
*Ничтожный человек, не имеющий никаких достоинств; ничтожество. Кто ты такой, ведь ты - никто! Он нас за никого считает.*

1. НИКТО, -1)
   Ни один (человек), ни одно (существо). Н. меня не понимает. Спичек ни у кого не нашлось. Никому не рассказывай. Ни с кем не встретился. /
   Как отрицательный ответ на вопрос. Кто тебя обидел? - Н.
   (меня вообще не обижали). Есть там кто-нибудь? - Никого
   (нет). С кем ты приедешь? - Ни с кем
   (приеду один или вообще не приеду). < Никто, никем; м. и ж. кому. в функц. сказ. Разг.

***О человеке постороннем, абсолютно чуждом кому-л. Он мне н. С тех пор она стала мне никем. Такие люди мне всегда были никто.***